# Formal definition on $\int^e_1 \frac{1}{x} \, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

**Question**. Find the integral $$\int^e_1 \frac{1}{x} \, dx$$ using the formal definition

**Attempt**. So considering that the formal definition is $$\int^b_a f(x) \, dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^n_{i=1}f(x_i) \, \Delta x$$ with $\Delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$ and $x_i=a+i \, \Delta x$. Applied to my problem I did this $\Delta x=\frac{e-1}{n}$ and $x_i=1+i\frac{e-1}{n}$ so using the formula we get $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^n_{i=1}\frac{e-1}{n(1+i\frac{e-1}{n})}$$ simplifying and bringing out constants we end up with $$(e-1) \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{1}{n+i(e-1)}$$ but I'm stuck here since I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: When the exercise says "using the formal definition", are you completely sure that it means the formal definition _of an integral_, rather than, for example, the formal definition of $e$? And in any case, what _is_ the definition of $e$ in your context?

Comment: For example, some textbooks follow a development where the relevant formal definitions unfold to, essentially, "$e$ is the unique positive real such that $\int_1^e \frac{dx}{x} = 1$".

Comment: what? But I'm sure it means the defn of the integral

Comment: Your goal should be to help people help you, @Acyex “What?” gives no clue what is confusing you, and actually reads as a little rude, because it implies everything person wrote was confusing.

Comment: Maybe you can use an FTC and see that $\frac{d}{dx} \ln(f(x)=x)=\frac{f’(x)}{f(x)}=\frac1x \implies \int \frac{dx}{x}=\ln(x)?$

Comment: @Thomas Andrews that is because it was confusing, I didn't understand it, the "what" was more of a "what do you mean", and I'm surprised how "what" is now rude, it simply express doubt? But i guess I'm sorry if it came out rude.

Comment: @Tyma Gaidash I really don't know what that is, but I'm wondering if the sum is even possible to do with the usual tools since wolfram alpha uses a phi function or something, if there is no other way I could try learning the FTC

Comment: @Acyex by FTC, I mean the fundamental theorem of calculus. You know the [logarithmic derivative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_derivative) already and can do some simple algebra to prove the integral using the FTC.

Comment: but I'm not seeing how that could be used with the integral definition, trying to evaluate the sum, is it usable on sums also? I'm quite confused